# Hi I am trying to only on tab according to the selected value Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

My code is

```
function showFields(){
  vm.activetab = '';

  if(vm.selectpage.name=='dashboard'){
    vm.activetab.main = true;  
  }else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'calender'){
    vm.activetab.calender = true;
  }else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'to_do'){
    vm.activetab.to_do = true;
  }else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'mobile_consumption'){
    vm.activetab.mobile_data_consumption = true;
  }else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'user_activity'){
    vm.activetab.mobile_data_consumption = true;
  }else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'using_applications'){
    vm.activetab.mobile_data_consumption = true;
  }else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'session_activity'){
    vm.activetab.activity_per_session = true;
  }
  console.log(vm.activetab.mobile_data_consumption);

 }
```

IN html side

```
  <div ng-if="vm.activetab.main" style="margin-top:20px">
  //code
</div>
<div ng-if="vm.activetab.calender" style="margin-top:20px">
  //code
</div>
<div ng-if="vm.activetab.to_do" style="margin-top:20px">
  //code
</div>
```

When the showfield function call it only show for the main but not for the others means when I choose the main it show and when I select the calendar it hides the main but doesnt show the calendar div

Comment: You're not setting any of the previously selected tabs to false. So the main will stay 'active' because it's the first ng-if - if you check dev tools I bet (for example) if you had selected calendar, it would be there, but hidden underneath the main tab.

Comment: I recommend you to use a `switch case` instead of multiple `if else`

Comment: I did empty the activetab variable

Comment: I think it's not the issue of using switch or if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figure out It was my mistake I haven't check the div opening and closing. everything was coming under the main.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it may hope it will work

```
else if(vm.selectpage.url == 'calender'){
   vm.activetab.calender = true;
    vm.activetab.main = false;  
   vm.activetab.to_do = false;
     }
```